# Why are my neural network predictions correct when applied to MNIST hand-drawn images, but incorrect when applied to my own hand-drawn images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

**Background:**

I am trying to create a basic neural network to recognize hand-drawn images using the MNIST dataset. I have things working when training/predicting against the MNIST data.

**Goal:**

I would like to start applying the model to non-MNIST images (i.e. hand-drawn images that I create myself).

**Problem:**

Every prediction of hand-drawn images that I create has ended up being incorrect (which is odd because predictions against MNIST images are 95% accurate).

**Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist # 28x28 images of handwritten digits (0-9)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(val_loss, val_acc)

# prediction from MNIST dataset
index_of_mnist_img = 0
predictionsA = model.predict([x_test])
print(np.argmax(predictionsA[index_of_mnist_img]))
plt.imshow(x_test[index_of_mnist_img], cmap = plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()

# prediction from my own hand-drawn image (THIS IS WHERE THINGS START GOING WRONG)
img = cv2.imread('4.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (28,28))
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = np.reshape(img, [1,28,28])
predictionsB = model.predict(img)
print(np.argmax(predictionsB[0]))
plt.imshow(predictionsB[0])
plt.show()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How many of your own images have you tested? Are they in the same format? Do they look the same as MNIST?

Comment: The mnist datset has 60,000 training images and 10,000 testing images. The training images, testing images, and my own images are all 28x28 pixels and are greyscale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you need to invert the colormap for your new (hand-drawn) image.

When I look at MNIST example images, I see something like this:

```
# show mnist image
index_of_mnist_img = 0
plt.imshow(x_test[index_of_mnist_img], cmap = plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
```

[image: 7]

However, if I make an example hand-written digit, and read it in as you have, I see an inverted image.

```
img = cv2.imread("4.png")
img = cv2.resize(img, (28,28))
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(img, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
```

[image: 4]

You can invert the image with OpenCV by adding one line, `cv2.bitwise_not()`.

```
img = cv2.imread(r"4.png")
img = cv2.resize(img, (28,28))
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img= cv2.bitwise_not(img) # invert image
plt.imshow(img, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
```

[image: 4_inverted]

When I invert the image, then I get correct predictions from the neural network you have trained above.

```
predictionsB = model.predict(img)
print(np.argmax(predictionsB[0]))
```

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need consider how to the train/test was created. This traning can be overrfited, with this, your give a good acurracity in train, but this is not trully whith test data.

Is also possible uses image augmentation to increase your dataset, because MNIST is a relative small dataset, and the numbers is centralized, the image does not have noise and etc.

And another concepts can be used, like Dropouts: The idea behind Dropouts is that they remove a random number of neurons in your neural network. This works very well for two reasons: The first is that neighboring neurons often end up with similar weights, which can lead to overfitting, so dropping some out at random can remove this.

Another thing is use Pooling Layers to reduce size of representation, with this it will detect more features.

Comment: Thanks for making me consider this, willteam. I'll try extracting an image from the MNIST dataset as a standalone image and test the above code against it. That will allow me to determine if its the code or the way I created my image. Thanks!